# options for using old sound drivers on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

i just found this old copy of elder scrolls redgaurd on archive.com (from 1998) https://archive.org/details/REDGUARDDemo

Do i have any options other than virtual machines for getting the sound drivers working. like maybe some modern windows 10 compatible version of sound blaster or something...

[image showing my options for drivers when installing game, compared with my actual drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtga6.png)

what would you do?

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing the driver in Compatibility mode when no other apps are running.  Close everything.

If it does not work then Virtual Machines are your only option.

Best to have a decent computer, 64-bit OS, and a fast SSD with lots of space to run virtual machines.

I have several VMs on board so the idea works fine.

Beware that VMs use the host hardware, so you will need to research which App you might use, studying to ensure you can use the driver.

**Footnote:**  I just loaded a Windows 98 machine with Soundblaster settings and sound works fine in Windows 98 using the host audio hardware. True in Windows 10 and true now in Windows 11.